# How to amend data in a different component?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue js and trying to build a simple CRUD example for myself.

Following the documentation on [non parent child communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) I would like to amend the `heading` value in the data of one component but from another component.

I set up [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/craigvantonder/abtgmx47/) to showcase the relative functionality as I currently understand it and we have here the HTML:

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <person-add></person-add>
  <person-list :list="people"></person-list>
</div>

<template id="person-add-template">
  <div>
    <h2>
      <span>{{ heading }}</span>
      Person
    </h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleFormSubmit">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter persons name" v-model="name" />
      <button type="submit" v-show="name">
        Add Person
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="person-list-template">
  <div>
    <h2>People</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Person</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(person, key) in list">
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td><button type="button" @click="editPerson(key)">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the JS:

```
// https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication
var bus = new Vue();
// Add
Vue.component('person-add', {
  template: '#person-add-template',
  props: ['list'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      heading: 'Add',
      name: ''
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    bus.$on('toggle-heading', function (newHeading) {
      console.log(newHeading);
      this.heading = newHeading;
    });
  }
});
// List
Vue.component('person-list', {
  template: '#person-list-template',
  props: ['list'],
  methods: {
    editPerson: function (key) {
      console.log('fired');
      bus.$emit('toggle-heading', 'Edit');
    }
  }
});
// Vue
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    people: [
      { name: 'Bob' },
      { name: 'Frank' },
      { name: 'Mary' }
    ]
  }
});
```

As you can see, it presents a simple form that starts with "Add Person" and lists some people along with an edit button for each:

[image: Person List]

What I would like to happen is that when I click on edit next to a persons name then it will change the heading in the other component to say "Edit Person" as opposed to the default "Add Person".

In the method in component A I have:

```
editPerson: function (key) {
  console.log('fired');
  bus.$emit('toggle-heading', 'Edit');
}
```

And in the created hook within component B I have:

```
created: function () {
  bus.$on('toggle-heading', function (newHeading) {
    console.log(newHeading);
    this.heading = newHeading;
  });
}
```

When I click edit, in the console I see the logs `fired` and then `Edit` so the event seems to follow through to the `person-add` component but where I have tried to assign the new heading `this.heading = newHeading;`, the heading does not change and I am battling to understand why.

If anyone could suggest why this is happening, where I have gone wrong with this or how things should be done if this is not the right way then it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually to do with scope, not a lack of understanding of Vue. Your code is correct, except you are trying to access `this` from inside a function creating it's own `this` context.

Whenever you create a new function this way, it creates it's own `this` so when you do:

```
bus.$on('toggle-heading',  function(newHeading) {
    console.log(newHeading);
    // this refers to this anonymous function only 
    this.heading = newHeading;
});
```

`this` only refers to the function itself, not the the `Vue` instance.

The way to get around this is to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which do not create their own `this`:

```
  bus.$on('toggle-heading',  (newHeading) => {
      console.log(newHeading);
      // No new 'this' context is created in an arrow function
      this.heading = newHeading;
    });
```

Or if you are not using `ECMAScript 2015` you will need to set a reference to `this` outside the function:

```
  var self = this; // set a reference to "this"

  bus.$on('toggle-heading',  function(newHeading) {
      console.log(newHeading);
      // Now self refers to the view models `this`
      self.heading = newHeading;
    });
```

I've updated your fiddle to show you the two methods:

Arrow Function: https://jsfiddle.net/abtgmx47/3/

Using `var self=this` reference: https://jsfiddle.net/abtgmx47/4/

Comment: When you say it like that then it makes perfect sense and is most obvious to me now. Thank you for your detailed explanation along with code and fiddles for possible options. I have been taught a few things here today, you deserve to overtake me in points, much appreciated :-)